# $σ$-algebra generated by countable disjoint sets

Tags: measure-theory

${S_1,…,S_N}$ is a partition of $Ω$ ($S_n$ are the atoms of $Ω$) such that any pair of elements of $S$ are disjoint, $⋃S=Ω$.

Then the $σ$-algebra generated by this collection is- ${\cal F}=\left\{\bigcup_{j∈J} S_j\mid J\subseteq {{1,…,N}}\right\}$.

I want to know how can I prove this.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

1. Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma-algebra.
2. Use 1. to conclude that $\sigma(\{S_1,\ldots,S_N\})\subseteq \mathcal{F}$.
3. Show the (trivial) inclusion $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\sigma(\{S_1,\ldots,S_N\})$.
4. Conclude.